# Drag all Divs. "this"

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I have this code for DnD an element. It works for an especific element. However I wanna make it work for all divs. I can't reference "this.id" to the move function. I don't what is missing to make it work.

```
window.addEventListener('load', init, false);
function init(){

      //just one element
   /* box = document.getElementById('div1');
    box.addEventListener('mousedown', startMoving, false);
    box.addEventListener('mouseup', stopMoving, false);*/

     //all element?
    box = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
    for (i=0;i<box.length;i++) {
        box[i].addEventListener('mousedown', startMoving, false);
        box[i].addEventListener('mouseup', stopMoving, false);
    }

}

 function startMoving(evt){
   evt = evt || window.event;
   var posX = evt.clientX, 
   posY = evt.clientY,
   a = document.getElementById(this.id);
   divTop = parseInt(a.style.top),
   divLeft = parseInt(a.style.left); 
   var diffX = posX - divLeft, 
   diffY = posY - divTop; 

   document.onmousemove = function(evt){ 
    evt = evt || window.event;
    var posX = evt.clientX, 
    posY = evt.clientY, 
    aX = posX - diffX, 
    aY = posY - diffY;
    move(this.id,aX,aY); 
        }
    }
function stopMoving(){ 
 document.onmousemove = function(){}
 }

  function move(divid,newX,newY){
    var a = document.getElementById(divid);
    a.style.left = newX + 'px';
    a.style.top = newY + 'px';
    }
```

Is there a better way to make this?

Comment: You don't even need `a = document.getElementById(this.id);` - just use `this` and you have a reference to the specific element.

Comment: this = null...I am using only "this" like you said. I saw on the inspector that: on startMoving, it refers to the actual div, but onmousemove it refers to the whole html...

Comment: You're using `document.onmousemove = function(evt){` - you need to use `this.onmousemove = function(evt){`

Comment: check my http://jsfiddle.net/eM5RG/

Comment: I got it... its calling move(this.id, aX, aY)..forgot the attribute

Comment: Again, instead of using the `id`, just use/pass `this` and use that reference. So in that case, pass `this` (instead of `this.id`), and then in your `move` function, change the parameter from `divid` to `div` and just use `div`

Comment: try this a = document.getElementById(evt.currentTarget.id);